# multiple geocoding request by gmaps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocode

I need to multiple geocoding request by gmaps api v3. In particular it work but only 5 request. This is my code (where city.length = 100):

```
for(i=0; i<city.length; i++) {

   $('#nome').html(city[i]);
   latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i],lng[i]);

   geocoder.geocode({
       'latLng': latLng,
       'partialmatch': true
   }, geocodeFunction);
}
```

Comment: Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day. (User of Google Maps API Premier may perform up to 100,000 requests per day.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I try to use is the google web service ;).
It work!